# Переход на другую страницу WordPress на локальном сервере

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю верстку на WordPress.
Использую OpenServer.
Мне нужно перейти с главной страницы на страницу О нас, у нее отдельный адрес "about.php"
Переход будет осуществлятся по нажатию на ссылку в Header.

Пробовал этот вариант, не переходит
`<li class="menu__item"> <a class="menu__link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>./about.php">О Нас</a> </li>`

Что нужно прописать в href, чтобы просто перейти на другую страницу?

Comment: Изобретаете велосипед. У вордвпресса имеется инструмент по созданию меню. Создаёте ваши страницы, добавляете их в меню, меню добавляете в шаблон вашей темы на вордпрессе. Всё. https://ru.wordpress.org/support/article/appearance-menus-screen/

Answer (score 1):

Почему вы используете the_permalink()? Эта функция выводит адрес конкретного поста. В Вашем случае надо, как понимаю, так

`<li class="menu__item"> <a class="menu__link" href="<?php echo home_url('/blog.php', 'https'); ?>">О Нас</a> </li>`

Если так не прокатит, то вызовите эту функцию без параметров, так:

`<li class="menu__item"> <a class="menu__link" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/blog.php">О Нас</a> </li>`

Comment: Открываеться та же главная страница, только с адресом /about.php